# Remove nodes that has a decendent that equals some value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to reduce a large XML using XSLT. I want to copy the whole XML, except:

Person elements with *at least* one decendent named "Enhetnavn" that matches a string. In other words, the following XML should output the top two person elements, but not the last:

```
<ArrayOfPerson>
    <Person>
        <Ansattforhold>
             <Ansatt>
                <Stillinger>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> Match </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
             </Ansatt>
        </ansattforhold>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Ansattforhold>
             <Ansatt>
                <Stillinger>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
             </Ansatt>
                <Stillinger>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> Match </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
             </Ansatt>
        </ansattforhold>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Ansattforhold>
             <Ansatt>
                <Stillinger>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
             </Ansatt>
                <Stillinger>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
                   <Stilling>
                       <Enhetsnavn> NotMatch </Enhetsnavn>
                   </Stilling>
             </Ansatt>
        </ansattforhold>
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

So Ive tried the following approach. However, if Person was reachable inside the loop (which it is not), I would return duplicates of Person.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ArrayOfPerson">
      <xsl:for-each select="Person/Ansattforhold/Ansatt">
          <xsl:for-each select="Stillinger/Stilling">
              <xsl:if test = "Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Austrått' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Trones A' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR Sone Rovik' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Riska' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Sone Lura' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Trones B' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Sone Åse' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR, Sone Åse B' or Enhetnavn = 'EHR,Byhagen B' and var_true = true">
                   <xsl:copy-of select="Person"/>
              </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Ive updatet my Q now with one approach I've tried now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the whole XML except some nodes, it would be best to start with the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template and add an empty template for the nodes you want to remove - for example:

**XML (well-formed!!!)**

```
<ArrayOfPerson>
  <Person>
    <Ansattforhold>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>Match</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
    </Ansattforhold>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Ansattforhold>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>Match</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
    </Ansattforhold>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Ansattforhold>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
    </Ansattforhold>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person[descendant::Enhetsnavn='Match']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson>
  <Person>
    <Ansattforhold>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
      <Ansatt>
        <Stillinger>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
          <Stilling>
            <Enhetsnavn>NotMatch</Enhetsnavn>
          </Stilling>
        </Stillinger>
      </Ansatt>
    </Ansattforhold>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

Comment: Forgot to thank you. So.. thank you! :) @michael.hor257k